# How to set ToLocalTime date format

Tags: c#, date-format

I want to set at one place to format to show tostring of datetime/
I want format to be "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" every time I write ToString() so it will be the default format .
I've tried

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(lang);
ci.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name)
```

without success.

Comment: Try also setting `ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go with the following.

You can add a extension method like this:

```
public static class LocalDateTime
{
    public static string ToLocalDateTime(this DateTime dt)
    {
       return dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

With the above, you can just call `datetimeObj.ToLocalDateTime();` instead of `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var ci = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/mm/yyyy";
ci.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting current culture like this:

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string thetime = DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.ToString(//yourtimeformat);
```

this brings the universal time

```
string thetime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString(//yourtimeformat);
```

your current system time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
ci.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = ci;

Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("D"));
```

It's worth to notice that I used DefaultThreadCurrentCulture. You can read more about this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx